# Call to undefined method CI_Form_validation::set_fields()

Tags: php, function, continuous-integration

when i try to add my the query in CodeIgniter i get this undefined method CI_Form_validation::set_fields(). Here is my Controller THIS gives me error and I am not able to update or add an entry into my database

```
function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            #load library dan helper yang dibutuhkan
            $this->load->library(array('table','form_validation'));
            $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->model('siswa_model','',TRUE);
        }
function add(){
            $this->_set_fields();

            #set common properties
            $data['title']='Tambah siswa baru';
            $data['message']='';
            $data['action']= site_url('siswa/addSiswa');
            $data['link_back']= anchor('siswa/index/','Back to list of siswas',array('class'=>'back'));

            $this->load->view('siswaEdit',$data);
        }

        function addSiswa()
        {
            $data['title']='Tambah siswa baru';
            $data['message']='';
            $data['action']= site_url('siswa/addSiswa');
            $data['link_back']= anchor('siswa/index/','Back to list of siswas',array('class'=>'back'));

            $this->_set_fields();
            $this->_set_rules();

            #run validation
            if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
                $data['message']='';

                }
            else
            {
                //save data
                $siswa=array('nama'=>$this->input->post('nama'),
                    'alamat'=>$this->input->post('alamat'),
                    'jenis_kelamin'=>$this->input->post('jenis_kelamin'),
                    'tanggal_lahir'=> date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('tanggal_lahir')))
                    );

                $id=$this->siswa_model->save($siswa);


                //set form input nama="id"
                $this->form_validation->id=$id;

                redirect('siswa/index/add_success');
            }
            $this->load->view('siswaEdit',$data);
        }

function _set_fields()
        {
            $fields['id'] = 'id';
            $fields['nama'] = 'nama';
            $fields['alamat'] = 'alamat';
            $fields['jenis_kelamin'] = 'jenis_kelamin';
            $fields['tanggal_lahir'] = 'tanggal_lahir';

            $this->form_validation->set_fields($fields);
        }
```

can you help me to check the error? in function __construct already to edit become but its not working

```
$this->load->library(array('form_validation'));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not set_fields($fields) method signature in the manual: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#tutorial.

What are you trying to do with your code?